# apache mod_rewrite to hide index.php but change rest of php files to directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well the title pretty much sums it up. I am trying to hide index.php but any other php files such as file.php would become /file/ etc...

I have this htaccess so far, but its not working...

```
Options -Indexes -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to hide `index.php` is to never link to it, it's not necessary and I don't know why people do it. Use `/` in your `href` to link to the web root, or `./` to link to the current directory.

```
# 404.php file should set status with header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# remove .php from legitimate requests (you should still update all the URLs served so that normal crawling/browsing doesn't 301 on every link)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S++\s++((/[^?\s]+?)??/index\.php)(\?\S*+)?\s [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S++\s++((/[^?\s]+?)\.php)(\?\S*+)?\s
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ %2/%3 [NS,NE,L,R=301]
# add trailing / to legitimate requests missing it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .+ $0/ [NS,NE,L,R=301]
# rewrite all requests that look like directories to files, /foo/ to /foo.php and /bar/baz/qux/ to /bar/baz/qux.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^./][^/]*+(?:/[^./][^/]*+)*)/$ $1.php [NS,L,DPI]
# allow everything else to be processed as normal file request or 404
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. You wrote "write all requests that look like directories to files" but I needed to change php files to directory, not directory to php file. Also the hide index.php i meant more in the way of, if a user types index.php it auto returns just the / and doesnt show the php.

Comment: So the php files no longer exist, and now the folders do? Or the the actual files are like `/bar/baz/qux.php` and you want the URL to *appear* to be `/bar/baz/qux/`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my solution. You never said you wanted an external redirect, only that you want `/file/` to resolve to `file.php`, which is done via internal rewrites.

Comment: no, i wanted file.php to become /file/ and index.php to become /. And if anyone phyically wrote the address as file.php it would automatically transfer to /file/ and so on...

Comment: @FoxyFish You're pretty ungrateful, eh? [Didn't answer my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093364/apache-mod-rewrite-to-hide-index-php-but-change-rest-of-php-files-to-directories/41098735?noredirect=1#comment69429875_41098735) nor pay attention to me editing the answer. If you don't want `/foo/` to be internally rewritten to `foo.php`, omit the last rule + condition. Maybe I should just delete my answer and stop trying to help you?

Comment: Ungrateful? i have no idea what your beef is, i never even said anything out of turn, just trying to get across what i am trying to achieve. All i wanted is for all my php pages to appear as directories.

Comment: Unresponsive to requests for clarification and apparently haven't even been bothered to try the code.

Comment: Hi Walf, sorry its taken so long to get back to you, i havent been well. Anyway i have just tried the code and found that the index redirects fine (first cond/rule), but the others do not, i just get a "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error for any other link but index.php. the addess bar does show that it removed the extension but its doing this "/file//" with 2 trailing slashes and saying "The page isn’t redirecting properly".

Comment: The second rule + condition is broken but, at this point, I'm not gonna fix it for you.

Comment: Huh? how come? can you at least tell me how its broken so i can try to fix it?

Comment: Actually not sure, now.